# Payment successful but cannot create order react stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to implement **stripe payment** and create order in my **database**. Even though my stripe payment is successful I'm unable to create order in database. My implementation  -
Shopping Cart:

```
import './ShoppingCart.css';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useNavigate }from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import logo from '../images/BritonStore.png';
import {userRequest} from '../requestMethods';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE;

const ShoppingCart = ({id}) => {
const cart = useSelector(state=>state.cart);
const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
const history = useNavigate();

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;
const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;
const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;
// console.log(TOKEN)
const width = window.innerWidth;

const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
  };

useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async ()=>{
        try{
            const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/pay", {
                tokenId:stripeToken.id,
                amount: cart.total,
            });
            console.log(res)
            history('/success', {stripeData: res.data, products: cart});
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
}, [stripeToken, cart.total, history])

return (
    <div>
        {cart.products.length === 0 && width < 451 ? 
        <div className='emt-cart'>
            <div className="emt-wrapper">
                <h2 className="emt-header">Your Bag is Empty.</h2>
                <div id="sc-empty-cart-animated-image" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/02/cart/empty/animated/rolling-cart-desaturated._CB405717979_.svg">
                <img alt="" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/02/cart/empty/animated/cart-fallback-desaturated._CB405717979_.svg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        : 
        cart.products.length === 0 && width > 451 ?         
        <div className="emt-pc-wrapper">
            <div className='emt-pc'>
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/02/cart/empty/kettle-desaturated._CB424695504_.svg" alt="" />
                <div className="emt-pc-text">
                    <h2>Your Bag is Empty</h2>
                    <Link to='/store'>Continue Shopping</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        :
        <div className='cartscreen'>
            <div className='cartscreen-title'>
                <h2>Review your bag.</h2>
                <p>Free delivery and free returns</p>
            </div>

{cart.products.map(product=>(
            <div className='cart' key={cart.products.id}>
                <div className='image'>
                    <img src={product.image} key={product._id}/>
                </div>
                <div className='details'>
                    <div className='title'>
                        <h3>{product.title}</h3>
                        <p>Product ID: {product._id}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='quantity'>
                        <p>Quantity: {product.quantity}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='total-price'>
                        <p>{product.price*product.quantity}$</p>
                        <p>Remove</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       ))}

            <div className='total'>
                <div className='left'>
                    <p>Subtotal</p>
                    <p>Shipping</p>
                </div>
                <div className='right'>
                    <p> {cart.total} $</p>
                    <p>Free</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='f-total'>
                <h4>Total</h4>
                <h4> {cart.total} $</h4>
            </div>
            <div className='checkout'>
                <div className='method'>
                    <h3>How would you like to checkout ?</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div className='method-cards'>
                    <div className='card'>
                        <h2>Proceed To Checkout</h2>
                        {TOKEN ? <StripeCheckout
                        name='Store'
                        image={logo}
                        billingAddress
                        shippingAddress
                        description={`Your total is $${cart.total}`}
                        amount={cart.total*100}
                        token={onToken}
                        stripeKey={"pk_test_51KLN11ITl57zrxjuYSYut39BpN1qKSqcUWCksXqFXJU95FxSIei4O4Lfb4BrH4Rc7hWN7rZRy7sbz2J7QCC08QSf00AwpDVnBB"}
                        >
                        <button className='btn-payment'>Pay Now!</button>
                        </StripeCheckout> : <p className='login-wrng'>Please <Link to='/login'>Login</Link> to continue payment</p>}
                        {TOKEN ? <p className='payment-methods'>We accept payments from PayPal, Visa, MasterCard</p> : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>}

    </div>
  )
}

export default ShoppingCart
```

**Success Screen/ Create Order Screen:** I believe the problem is in line `[  const data = location.state.stripeData;
const cart = location.state.cart;]`. the screen goes blank and console says **"cannot read properties of undefined stripeData." location = useLocation() returns state null.**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { userRequest } from '../requestMethods';

const Success = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const data = location.state.stripeData;
  const cart = location.state.cart;
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const createOrder = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post("/orders", {
          userId: currentUser._id,
          products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
            productId: item._id,
            quantity: item._quantity,
          })),
          amount: cart.total,
          address: data.billing_details.address,
        });
        setOrderId(res.data._id);
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
    data && createOrder();
  }, [cart, data, currentUser]);
  return (
    <div>
      {orderId
        ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is ${orderId}`
        : `Failed...`}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Success
```

order model -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userId: {type: String, required: true, unique:true},
        products: [
            {
                productId: {type: String},
                quantity: {type: Number, default: 1},
                
            },
        ],
        amount: {type:Number, required:true},
        address: { type: Object, required:true },
        status: {type: String, default: 'pending'},
    }, {timestamps: true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

order route -

```
const Order = require("../models/Order");
const {
  verifyToken,
  verifyTokenAndAuthorization,
  verifyTokenAndAdmin,
} = require("./verifyToken");

const router = require("express").Router();

//CREATE
router.post("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  const newOrder = new Order(req.body);

  try {
    const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add some additional logging to capture how far you code execution progresses prior to any error being raised.  Is your Order create function being called?  

Have you thought about using webhooks and the `charge.succeeded` event to monitor orders?

Answer (score 0):

1. create **orderRedux.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const OrderSlice = createSlice({
  name: "order",
  initialState: {
    orders: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    //Add order
    addOrderStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    addOrderSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.orders.push(action.payload);
    },
    addOrderFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
  },
});
export const {
  addOrderFailure,
  addOrderStart,
  addOrderSuccess,
} = OrderSlice.actions;
export default OrderSlice.reducer;
```

2. Then we create a function to call the redux in the **apiCalls.js**

```
import { userRequest } from "../requestMethods";
import { addOrderFailure, addOrderStart, addOrderSuccess } from "./orderRedux";

export const addOrder = async (order, dispatch) => {
  // console.log(order)
  dispatch(addOrderStart());
  try {
    const res = await userRequest.post("orders", order)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    dispatch(addOrderSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(addOrderFailure());
  }
};
```

3. Then in the **ShoppingCart** script,

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

4. call the function we created **addOrder** , after the payment is successful

```
history('/success', {stripeData: res.data, products: cart});
 let order;
        cart.products.map((item) => {
          order = {
            userId: user._id,
            proudcts: [{ productId: item._id }, { quantity: item.quantity }],
            amount: item.quantity * item.price,
            address: res.data.billing_details.address,
            statusorder: "pending"
          }
        });
        addOrder(order, dispatch);
      } catch { }
```

At the end in your **success** script, fetch the requests from your **api**.
I hope this solution helps you ✨

Answer (score -1):

i don't know if you solved it but i am certain that someone else will find my answer worthwhile. since react-router-dom v6, useHistory() hook was replaced with useNavigate(). you will need to use useNavigate() instead of useHistory(). so your code will be like:

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const navigate = useNavigate()

...
navigate("/success", {state: {data: res.data})

this is the new way, i hope that you will understand my solution and implement it in your code.